# "Can't get last text item of alias" Error When Running AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript that runs as part of a Hazel routine monitoring a folder.  When the script runs, it picks apart the file targeted by the Hazel routine and then attaches the file to an email and addresses the email with information from the name of the file.  Unfortunately, it seems there is an error somewhere in the script, but I cannot seem to locate it.

The only semi-useful information from Console is in the title (i.e., "Can't get last text item of alias").  Here is the script:

```
on hazelProcessFile(theFile)

    set theAttachment1 to (POSIX path of theFile)
    set FileName to theFile

    --remove trailing slash
    set SansSlash to quoted form of text 1 through -2 of FileName
    set FileName to SansSlash as text

    -- remove path from FileName
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set SansPath to last text item of FileName
    set FileName to SansPath as text

    -- remove extension
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    set SansExtension to every text item of FileName
    set last text item of SansExtension to ""
    set FileName to SansExtension as text

    -- parse using —
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "—"
    set clientName to first text item of FileName
    set clientEmail to last text item of FileName

    tell application "Airmail 2"
        activate
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"New Invoice from ", content:"Please find attached, infra, the current month's invoice.    If you have any questions, please feel free to respond to this email.  One-time payments may be made using the following secure form on our website: https://.  Thank you for your continued business."}
        tell theMessage
            set sender to "billing@example.com"
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:clientName, address:clientEmail}
            make new mail attachment with properties {filename:theAttachment1}
            compose
        end tell
    end tell
end hazelProcessFile
```

The code is commented, so it should be obvious what each section is *supposed* to do.  I would imagine the issue is in the "remove path from FileName" section, as that is the section that has been giving me the most trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theFile` is obviously an `alias` specifier.
`text item` and `text thru` – as the name implies – expects plain text

You have to coerce the `alias` first to `text` before dealing with text and remove `quoted form of`, that's only needed in conjunction with `do shell script`.

```
--remove trailing slash
  set FileName to theFile as text
  set SansSlash to text 1 through -2 of FileName
  set FileName to SansSlash
```

but there is no trailing slash in a HFS path

To strip the file name without extension from an `alias` this is much easier

```
tell application "System Events" to set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to theFile
set baseName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & Ex in Nm) - 1) of Nm
```

**Edit:**

Try this optimized code, the `Airmail 2` part is skipped and I don't know if the EM Dash character is treated correctly in case you'll copy and paste the code.

```
on hazelProcessFile(theFile)

    set theAttachment1 to (POSIX path of theFile)
    tell application "System Events" to set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to theFile
    set FileName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & Ex in Nm) - 1) of Nm

    -- parse using —
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "—"}
    set clientName to text item -2 of FileName
    set clientEmail to text item -1 of FileName
    set text item delimiters to TID

    -- tell application "Airmail 2"
    -- ...

end hazelProcessFile
```

Comment: That change definitely made the script get further before failing (and thanks for the `quoted form of` tip).  However, I am now receiving this error in Console:

`NSLocalizedDescription = "File /Volumes/Storage/Dropbox/Company/Invoices/Invoice Staging/To Be Emailed/client\U20142015-12-29-2015-INV-1008\U2014client@example.com.pdf wasn\U2019t found.";`

Comment: It's actually not giving me a line number.  The only other error I see cropping up is `OSAScriptErrorNumberKey = "-43";`.  The whole sequence of events in the Hazel script is as follows: Hazel

1. checks the folder for files containing certain strings (this works as expected).
2. renames according to a pattern (file name—email—extension; i.e., it inserts the email).
3. runs the script, *supra*, and then
4. moves the file to an archive folder.

Currently the script errors out, Hazel tries to rerun its routine, and the file ends up with the email added a dozen or so times (I usually delete it).

Comment: Found it.  Somehow a slightly older version of the script with an extraneous `as alias` after `filename:theAttachment1` was in use.  With your suggested edits, it looks like the script is working now (although Hazel is still having trouble attaching the file to the email successfully, but I suspect that is an issue with Hazel or with El Capitan).

Comment: I updated the answer with a slightly optimized code. Look into the dictionary of Airmail what type is expected for the  `filename` parameter representing the attachment.

Comment: The optimized code works flawlessly with one minor edit: I change the `-2` to `-3` as the filename format in use is "Client Name—Date-Inv-#—email.pdf".  Of course, Hazel/El Capitan is still having trouble processing the attachment of the file to the generated email, but I'm going to have to open another thread for that issue as it's Hazel-specific, and unlikely to be related to this script.

Comment: Try a `delay 1` line before `compose`

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried with a simplified version of the script a bit earlier today (I did have a very simple version working, but it had too much hard coded).  I've opened another thread on the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518158/hazel-fails-to-attach-file-to-email-el-capitan

I am beginning to suspect the issue lies with El Capitan, which is not comforting.